# How to enable sudo commands over SSH without asking password?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, sudo

I have server A and server B (both Ubuntu 10.04 LTS) doing different tasks. Server A needs to poke Server B, which generates a file and scp's it back to server A when done. This is all in-house and I am not too concerned about security issues. SSH Key exchange is already performed between servers A and B and works fine.

On server B, the script `generateOfflineSig` looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "in script"
sudo apt-offline set offline_package.sig --install-packages "$0"
echo "after sudo"
scp offline_package.sig jeff@servera:/tmp
```

Also on server B, visudo has this entry:

> `jeff ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`

Which works if I execute `sudo ls` on Server B... no password asked.

Unfortunately SSH always asks for a password on Server A:

```
jeff@servera:~$ ssh -t jeff@serverb /home/jeff/generateOfflineSig "incron"
in script
[sudo] password for jeff:
```

Any ideas? This process can't be interrupted by password input.

Comment: Not 100% sure of `/etc/sudoers` syntax, but my file has the line `# %wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`. Maybe your line should be `jeff ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`?

Comment: Doesn't the entire remote command have to be in quotes? You might be executing the script on Sever A

Comment: Actually... I think snapshoe is on to something. I'll answer my own question a bit later...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It seems like I had a "typo" in the `/etc/sudoers` file...

`jeff ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`

needed to be at the **very end** of file. [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Remove_Password_Prompt_For_sudo) only says *Add (...) to the END of the file (if not at the end it can be nullified by later entries)*

After that, password is never asked for "jeff's sudo commands, either locally or over SSH.